# Cmake: how to force it to use colormake?

Tags: cmake

in order to use colormake I did set this alias in my .bashrc

```
alias make="/usr/bin/colormake"
```

It works, as if I try to compile (with qmake) a simple C++ example code with errors (just a main.cpp with a cout ), they are correctly coloured.

However, if I compile the same code with cmake, colormake is not used. What can I do to force cmake to use it?

my minimal CMakeList.txt example is

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.0.2)
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-std=c++11)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(exe main.cpp)
```

System: Debian 8.8 jessie

Thanks, Valerio

Update:

I modified the CMakeLists.txt in this way, but no success:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.0.2)
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-std=c++11)
set(CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM /usr/bin/colormake)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(exe main.cpp)
message("CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM: " ${CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM})
```

Update 2:

I modified the CMakeList in this way:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.0.2)
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-std=c++11)
#set(CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE OFF)
#set(CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM /usr/bin/colormake)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(exe main.cpp)
message("CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM: " ${CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM})
message("CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE: " ${CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE})
```

then launched cmake with this argument from command line:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/usr/bin/colormake -DCMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE=OFF ../
```

But again, the main.cpp synthax error after make is not coloured.
This is the output of cmake, note the messages about CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM and CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM: /usr/bin/colormake
CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE: OFF
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/valeriosperati/Desktop/VALERIO_SPERATI/prova_codice_c/colormake/cmake/build
```

Some additional (maybe helpful) info: this is the output
I obtain when compiling with qmake, the error 'hjskf' is in red.

[image: coloured output if using qmake]

this is the output when comiling with cmake:

[image: output if using cmake]

Comment: have same problem , and i have no solution yet .

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough to set the [`CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM.html) cache variable to point at the build tool you want to use. You can do this by running `cmake` with a `-D` option like so:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/usr/bin/colormake path/to/src
```

For the benefit of others, this technique can be used with other generators too, not just `make`. Just be aware that it is your responsibility to make sure the build tool specified matches the generator type CMake is using (i.e. don't pass a `make` tool if you've told CMake to use Ninja with `-G Ninja` instead).

Note, however, that this only really matters if you are invoking the build via CMake like so:

```
cmake --build path/to/build/dir
```

Some IDE tools may invoke the build that way. Most of the time, however, developers invoke the tool directly. In your case, you can simply invoke `colormake` instead of `make`. If you are *still* not getting colored output after doing that, then your problem must be elsewhere (check your terminal type settings perhaps).

Comment: Well, I tried but no success: I added the row: set(CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM /usr/bin/colormake) to my CMakelists.txt but the make output continues to be the same, no color!

Comment: Set it from the cmake command line rather than within your CMakeLists.txt

Comment: No success! Please see update 2. Note I tried  with and without -DCMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE=OFF as I suspected cmake uses its own system of coloring the output: CmakeFiles error are in fact coloured in light blue, while my syntax error remains gray (colormake should color it in red)!

Comment: I'm assuming you are doing all of this from a command line not an IDE. How are you initiating the build after you've run `cmake`? There are basically two choices: invoke the build tool directly, in which case you can guarantee you are using colormake yourself, or you use `cmake --build` in which case `CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM` will be used (I do this with Ninja builds on machines where it is not on the PATH).

Comment: I run cmake from command line in the build folder (the source main.cpp and CmakeList.txt are in the parent folder. I also tried using cmake-gui, but the result is the same. About 'initiating the build' I'm not sure I understand: what does it mean? I generally run  cmake (and arguments) and then make, that's all. Did I miss something?